# Tranfer text files through FTP from Powerbuilder 8

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a requirement to ftp some text files from my local macine to a server path by using Power builder 8. Can someone please assisi on how this can be achieved

Answer (score 2):

Roland Smith has some free code that implements this in PB8 and PB10.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_ftpclient.html

-Paul-